# How to set the x axis dynamically in androidplot when drawing a set of time series data

Tags: android, androidplot

I want to draw a set of time series data, received from the Bluetooth. The Y axis data can be drawn successfully in androidplot. But how can I set the value of X axis?

Answer (score 0):

Use the method useImplicitXVals();

```
private SimpleXYSeries series = new SimpleXYSeries(""); 
series.useImplicitXVals();
```

It will use index value as xVal, instead of explicit, user provided xVals.

For using explicit values

```
 xVal1 =0;
 for(int i=0;i<maxPoints;i++){
      series0.addFirst(xVal1, yVal);
      xVal1++; // change as per your xVal requirement
 }
```